# UICollectionViewCell rendering issues with scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with rows with variable height. It renders fine for the first four cells, but when scrolled, the new cells have wrong dimension and data from the previous rows.

The cell is set up with two UIViews -- headerView and entryView. The header view is hidden or shown based on a flag; the entry view can be either A or B and they have different height.

Here are delegate methods for the UICollectionView:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Entry *entry = self.entries[indexPath.row];
    [cell setEntry:entry showHeader:showHeader];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = [self cellHeight:self.entries[indexPath.row]];
    return size;
}
```

In the MyCell nib, I have two UIViews, `headerView` and `entryView`. The entryView's content changes based on type. Also based on `showHeader` flag, I show/hide the header view.

```
[ UIView - header view ]
[ UIView - entry view ]
```

In the MyCell implementation,

```
@interface ActivityCell ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *entryView;
@end

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *objects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        [self.contentView addSubview:objects[0]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setEntry:(Entry *)entry {
    _entry = entry;

    if (self.entry.entryType == TypeA) {
        EntryAView *entryA = [[EntryAView alloc] init];
        entryA.entry = entry;
        [self.entryView addSubview:entryA];
    } else if (self.entry.entryType == TypeB) {
        EntryBView *entryB = [[EntryBView alloc] init];
        entryB.entry = entry;
        [self.entryView addSubview:entryB];
    }
}

- (void)setEntry:(Entry *)entry showHeader:(BOOL)showHeader {
    if (showHeader) {
        UserHeader *userHeader = [[UserHeader alloc] init];
        userHeader.user = entry.user;
        [self.userView addSubview:userHeader];
        self.userView.hidden = NO;
        self.topConstraint.constant = UserHeaderHeight;
    } else {
        self.userView.hidden = YES;
        self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
    }
    self.entry = entry;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    NSArray *userViewsToRemove = [self.userView subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in userViewsToRemove) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSArray *entryViewsToRemove = [self.entryView subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in entryViewsToRemove) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.entry = nil;
}
```

- I'm calculating height of cell in `cellHeight` which returns correct CGSize.
- After researching, I added `prepareForReuse` in the cell, which seems to help, but doesn't fix the issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a concurrency problem. Try adding:

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

to your **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method.